# Parameterization of Ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, spherical-coordinates, parametrization

I have a question asking me to evaluate $\iint_\Sigma \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}~dS$, where $\Sigma$ is the lower half of the ellipsoid $z = -2 \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$ with $\mathbf{n}$ directed upwards. However, I'm having trouble deriving the parametric equations for $\Sigma$. I know the general form of the parametric equations for an ellipsoid, but I'd like to be able to recover them given a temporary lapse of memory (say, on an exam).

If I attempt to derive an expression for $\rho$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\theta$ using spherical coordinates, I end up with a messy expression that doesn't conform to the expected answer. On the other hand, letting $x = a \sin \phi \cos \theta$, $y = b \sin \phi \sin \theta$ and $z = c \cos \phi$ and solving for $a$, $b$ and $c$ gives the expected answer. But this procedure doesn't seem correct, because these don't look like spherical coordinates. Perhaps someone can explain how to derive the parametric equations systematically?

Comment: You can turn spheres into ellipsoids by applying appropriate scale factors along the Cartesian coordinate axes. Looks fine to me.

Comment: I think my confusion arises because the substitutions to transform rectangular into spherical coordinates in my textbook are given in terms of $\rho$, but in order to parameterize the ellipsoid in spherical coordinates I had to replace $\rho$ with $a$, $b$ and $c$. Is this some other closely related coordinate system, or am I misunderstanding something about spherical coordinates?

Comment: You’ve effectively composed two coordinate transformations. First, you scaled the Cartesian coordinate system so that the ellipsoid became a sphere, then you converted that to spherical coordinates. Try visualizing it this way: $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$ describes a family of concentric spheres, the surfaces $\rho=\text{const}$ in spherical coordinates; $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=\rho^2$ describes a family of similar (homothetic, actually) ellipsoids that correspond to those spheres in the scaled coordinate system.